# Failed to unpack the Windows 10 Core installation package

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi3, iot, windows-10-iot-core

While using the Microsoft IoT dashboard to install windows 10 IoT on a SD card i ran into the error "Failed to unpack the Windows 10 Core installation package". I tried on a different SD Card Class 10 and started the dashboard as Administrator but still getting the same error.

Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue, you can check the [compatible hardware list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist) for SD card.

You can try [DISM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/dism) instead of Dashboard as a workaround.

1. [Download](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/downloads) ISO image.
2. Install ISO image you will get flash.ffu under this path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft IoT\FFU\RaspberryPi2